# jQuery navigation with "hide delay"

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created the following navigation (sources can be found below my target and problem description).

**Target**

What I'd like to have as a final result is: As soon as you hover a navigation point the subnvaigation is showing. When you change a navigation point all other main navigation (including subnavigation) points should hide directly, but when you leave the complete navigation, there should be a delay of some seconds, before everything is hidding.

**Problem**

When I navigate over the first point "Home" the subnavigation point "News" is showing up. As soon as I leave "Home" there is the 250ms delay until "News" is disappearing, so far so good.

Now if I try to move the mouse to the subnavigation point "News" it is hiding in the second when I leave the first navigation point "Home".

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
      <ul id="dropdown">
            <li>
                  <a href="#">Home</a>
                  <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                  <a href="#">Navlevel 1</a>
                  <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Navlevel 2</a></li>
                        <li>
                              <a href="#">Navlevel 2</a>
                              <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Navlevel 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Navlevel 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Navlevel 3</a></li>
                              </ul>
                        </li>
                  </ul>
            </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* NAVIGATION ELEMENTS */
ul#dropdown
{
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul#dropdown ul
{ 
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

ul#dropdown ul ul,ul#dropdown ul ul ul
{
    top: -1px;
    left: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

ul#dropdown li
{
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    width: 165px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
    line-height: 50px;
}

ul#dropdown ul li
{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #e1e6e8;
    border: 0;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

/* Root Menu */
ul#dropdown a
{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

ul#dropdown li:hover a:hover
{
    font-weight: bold;
}


/* 2nd Menu */
ul#dropdown li:hover li a
{
    float: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
    width: 153px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #000000;
}

/* 2nd Menu Hover Persistence */
ul#dropdown li:hover li a:hover
{
    background-color: #aab6bb;
}
/* END NAVIGATION ELEMENTS */
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#dropdown li').mouseenter(function() {
      $('#dropdown li').not(this).children('ul').hide(); // Hide other child lists
      $(this).children('ul').show(); // Show this one
});
$('#dropdown').mouseleave(function() {
      var lists = $('li ul', this);
      setTimeout(function() {
            lists.hide(); // Hide all lists
      }, 250); // After 1/4 second
});
```

I hope there is someone who can help me with that problem. Let me know if you need any additional information.

Thanks a lot,
Rolf

Comment: can you paste the code in jsfiddle and provide the users with a simple link they can look at.(jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated (code as well as jsfiddle URL):** 
here s a jsfiddle with the desired result
http://jsfiddle.net/7PFDv/

*The only thing I added in your CSS was a dark background(so that the nav could be seen) and the following*

```
ul#dropdown ul
{
    display: none;
}
```

*And I edited your jquery to the following*

```
$('#dropdown li').mouseenter(function() {

      $(this).children('ul').show(); // Show this one
});

$('#dropdown>li').mouseleave(function() {

      //$(this).children('ul').hide(); // Show this one
    var lists = $(this).find('ul');
      setTimeout(function() {
            lists.hide(); // Hide all lists
      }, 250); // After 1/4 second

});

$('#dropdown>li li').mouseleave(function() {

      $(this).children('ul').hide(); // hide this one

});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick answer!


there is one more thing which is not working as expected. When you leave the navigation there is a delay in hiding the first subnavigation (nav 2), but all other subnavigations (nav 3) are closing instantly, is there a possibility that all subnavigations have a delay when leaving the mainnavigation? 

Hope you know what I mean. Thanks a lot!

Comment: sure, here s another fiddle demonstrating it: http://jsfiddle.net/saganbyte/hF5JK/1/

Comment: thanks again, I'm sorry to say but it's still not 100% right :) Maybe because I didn't explain it very well... I created a new fiddle to demonstrate the problem, here is the link: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/EfbT7/) - now if you start moving the mouse over the different navigations points there is also a hide delay when switching between subnavigation points, so they stay in the background, what doesn't look that nice. Do you see any possibilty to fix that? Cheers, Rolf